# How should I build the architecture of my MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I have a project about e-Sports. In this project, I have **VDS Game Servers** for players. With this game servers, our players will play **Ranked Games** and players will earn **Matchmaking Rank Points** for their rankings. When 10 players match in web application/desktop application/mobile application; the system will choose a server which one is idle and game will start. After the start of game, the status of **Server** will need to be changed real-time.

For example, Team A has 9 score and Team B has 10 score. When Team A got one more point, the match status should be **[Team A 10 - 10 Team B]** and I can get this changed in database.

---

Server documents look like this:

```
{
    ip: address.split(':')[0],
    port: address.split(':')[1] || 27015,
    pass: pass,
    live: false,
    map: '',
    maps: [],
    knife: false,
    score: [],
    round: 0,
    knifewinner: false,
    paused: false,
    freeze: false,
    unpause: {
        'TERRORIST': false,
        'CT': false
    },
    ready: {
        'TERRORIST': false,
        'CT': false
    },
    steamid: [],
    admins: [],
    queue: [],
    players: {},
    banner: '',
    pool: [],
    banned: [],
    picked: [],
    stats: ''
};
```

---

### The Question

Should I use MongoDB for real-time changes (updates) in this project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use MongoDB for real-time changes (updates) in this project?

Yes, you can use MongoDB for real-time updates. There are two options available for real-time updates based on whether you are using [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas)(Fully Managed Cloud MongoDB service) or Self managed MongoDB service.

1. Self Managed(On-Prem/Cloud) - From MongoDB 3.6 the new feature [Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) got introduced. Change streams allow applications to access real-time data changes without the complexity and risk of tailing the oplog. Applications can use change streams to subscribe to all data changes on a single collection, a database, or an entire deployment, and immediately react to them.
2. MongoDB Atlas - This comes with a service called [Stitch Triggers](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/triggers/). This will enable you to execute application and database logic automatically, either in response to events or based on a pre-defined schedule. This is the backend uses the Change Streams functionality.

So MongoDB should be a perfect option for your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I got the main idea :)